# How to completely uninstall webstorm on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, webstorm

I am trying to remove Webstorm editor completely from my Ubuntu 14.04, I have already tried by removing its installation folder but its settings still exists, is there any command exist to remove it completely or what any other way? please help me out?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: @Leon Downloaded WebStorm-9.0.1.tar.gz and after extracting ran bin/webstorm.sh

Comment: OK, so there in no install you just ran it out of the directory? And now there is config left behind somewhere and you want it removed?

Comment: yes, I want to remove its config..and don't know where its is

Comment: To those who closed this question, ummm Webstorm editor is completely for programming purposes (web development). Does it not then meet the requirement of "...tools used primarily for programming. ...".
If you believe this is off topic because it could be handled in some other community then shouldn't it be moved to that community?
Just saying...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

According to the WebStorm documentation, the config is stored in  `~/.WebStorm9`

So assuming you did not change the default location: from the command line run

```
rm -rf ~/.WebStorm9
```

## Update

For versions around the year 2020 you should go to the `~` and find `.config` and `.cache` folder and then delete your specific folder version inside `JetBrains` folder:

```
~/.config/JetBrains/<product><version>
~/.cache/JetBrains/<product><version>
```

Comment: Thanks,yes it is in `home/<user>/.WebStorm9`  as a hidden directory.

Comment: I have logged in just to give you an upvote. Thanks.

Comment: Also you should check  ~/.java/.userPrefs/prefs.xml

Comment: not working for me